# WBFGRID ISSUE IN QTP

Tags: save, qtp

My issue is wbfgrid. This is products page to select the products and then save the selected products. Following is what I have done:

I select the cell and set the data. After which click the save button. It seems like easy steps. I have tried following to select the cell and set the data. But it seems like nothing I selected gets saved. Please help!

```
Browser(" Sales").Page("Sales").Frame("Op Prod").WebElement("WebTable").Click 2,8    
Browser("Sales").Page("Sales").Frame("Op Prod").WebElement("WebTable").Object.innertext="2"  

 If  Browser("Sales").Page("Sales").Frame("Op Prod").WebButton("Save").Exist Then
```

After save line gets executed it does not save.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that QTP supports WbfGrid objects as long as the object's class name contains `DataGrid` or the object's id contains `DataGrid` or `GridView`? If not, you can just use a normal `WebTable` object. Try to stay away from the `WebElement` objects unless strictly necessary.

Normally a DataGrid is just a webtable with other objects like webedits or weblists in it. You need to extract these objects and setting these objects to the correct value:

```
' Get the first webedit (with index 0) on row 2, column 8
Set WebEditObj = Browser("Sales").Page("Sales").Frame("Op Prod").WbfGrid("WebTable").ChildItem(2, 8, "WebEdit", 0)

' Set the value of the webedit to 2
WebEditObj.Set "2"
```